# Loading a custom kernel module

Tags: android, kernel-module

My company is researching a possible port of our Linux application to Android. One of the key parts of this application is our kernel module. I have no idea about how Android devices work and no device at hand, but i have an extensive Linux kernel experience. I can imagine a way to build an LKM for Android but i have absolutely no idea is it actually possible for an Android application to setup its custom kernel module for loading on an Android device. Do Android devices actually run module-enabled kernels? If yes is it possible for an Android application to somehow load a kernel module directly (via insmod) or indirectly (by dropping a kernel module and modifying boot scripts to load it on device startup for example)?

It is not necessary for the app itself to be able to load modules but to modify the system once to load my module on startup (by a kind of installer application if you will).

I am aware of the possibility to build your own Android kernel with module support and imaging it on the device but this is not an option for an end-user application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible on an unrooted device. Loading custom kernel modules means you have full control over the system, and Android 3rd party apps are not supposed to have such control.

Comment: It is not necessary for the app itself to be able to load modules but to modify the system once to load my module on startup (by a kind of installer application if you will).

Comment: You can't really install anything but simple apps. So even if you're are planning to write one-time installer it will still be an app. And it won't be granted required permissions.