# Detection of access to the file system?

Tags: android, file, controls

I would like to make a antivirus, but so detect when an application create a file on the SD card for example. But I can t find a method to detect log the acces on the FS or create a file by an other application.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed. It's a valid question (although not phrased as a question). Of course, if you don't care about security, I could see what you closed it @casperOne.

Answer (score 3):

Use `FileObserver`.   [Here](http://www.roman10.net/android-fileobserverthe-underlying-inotify-mechanism-and-an-example/) is a description.

However, be warned that the `FileObserver` API does not allow you to block the file operations.  You will only be able to react to them after the fact.  By that time the application that has written the file may be already gone.

If your intention is to create a robust general antivirus (or to learn how one could be created), you will need to go a harder way.  Learn about `avflt` and `redirfs` [kernel modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368995/loading-a-custom-kernel-module),  learn to [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29) your device and to load these modules.

If you succeed, you will be able to use the [libav](http://www.redirfs.org/svn/redirfs/trunk/doc/libav/libav.txt) library, reliably detect the calling process (`av_event.pid`) and be able to delay or reliably deny requests that you don't like.

You will still not be in a good position to market your antivirus generally because of various issues with rooting, but it is about the only sound approach for the general task technically.

Comment: Thank you very much Jirka,
To block is not very important in my case, but I need to know the name of application that asks the access. I saw nothing in fileObserver that shows the process. It is possible to know?

Thanks

Comment: @user1433989 - This cannot be done reliably in principle.  `FileObserver` does not report access requests, but actions already taken.  If you get the event after the file has been completely written (and that can happen with `FileObserver`), and maybe the writer process even managed to exit, there is no answer you could hope to get.  If you are interested in an imperfect solution, search for `lsof`.  That only works while the file is still open, though.

Comment: Thank you very very much.  I will work .And "inotifyd" with the busybox is a good way ?

Comment: `FileObserver` uses `inotify` internally and it gives you a much easier API (assuming you only want to target Android and not desktops).  `inotify` does not provide a way to get writing process IDs or deny access.

Comment: But FileObserver in android wont give recursive events, i mean if a file observer is on /sdcard only files/folders created in /sdcard will rise events. if a file/directory created or modified inside /sdcard/music events wont be fired. For this FileObserver should be registered on every folder

Comment: @kishore - And the same is true of `inotify` as well.